# How to do asymmetric encryption without calling HashiCorp vault?

Tags: encryption, hashicorp-vault

When using the [transit secret engine of HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/transit/index.html), the vault has to be called to encrypt data.

Now, I have the situation that I want to encrypt data in an insecure location, where I can't store the credentials for the encryption service. For those situations, asymmetric encryption is the perfect answer. I can use the public key to encrypt the data in the insecure location without calling the vault. But later, I can call the vault from a secure location to decrypt the same data.

From what I see, Vault only supports rsa-2048 and rsa-4096 which can't be used for large data. All other ciphers are symmetric.

Do I misunderstand something here or does HashiCorp only support asymmetric encryption for small data?

Comment: Don't encrypt the data with the public key. Generate a random symmetric key, use that to encrypt the data (with, say, AES), then have Vault encrypt the symmetric key and store/transmit both the encrypted data and the encrypted symmetric key.

Comment: See [the data key API](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/encryption-as-a-service/eaas-transit).